# AccountsManager.get(this).getAccounts is Always 0

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am targeting my app to API 27 and calling getAccounts on Account manager and still I get 0 Result.

I have asked for permissions

```
  android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
  android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS

  Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
    if(accounts.length == 0){
        return null;
    }
```

accounts is always 0

Comment: You should be asking run time permissions from android 6.0 or higher.

Comment: I am asking above 2 mentioned runtime permission. It seems like Android Api 27 doesn't support getAccounts directly as mentioned here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#aaad . I am looking for other way around